# AngularJS $http.get "Unexpected token ..."

Tags: angularjs, get

I try to get a string from a .txt file from another server.

When I run the request, the console shows me this error:

"Unexpected token /"
The / is a placeholder, the error contains the first letter of the string on the server.

My code:

```
var url = "http://r0bs.net/ihdccjsonapi.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(content);
$http.get(url)
  .success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

When you navigate manual to the url you see this:

Familie. Beruf. Freizeit. Egal, was Sie vorhaben, mit dem Golf Variant machen Sie immer eine sportliche Figur. Entdecken Sie das Auto fÃ¼r einen aktiven Lebensstil.

The Error for this url is "unexpected token F"

I can't post the url here, i hope you can help me.

Varha

Comment: Have you access to the code on server, if yes show how it is handling the request? On which console you see the error, client or server side? What is the encoding of your text file, are you reading it with correct encoding? Show the result of encodeURIComponent(content).

Comment: @UlukBiy i can access and read JSON and images, plain text too

Comment: Have you tried to add text/plain to your $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common ?

Comment: @Iborgav how? i didn't try this

Answer (score 8):

You can try to set a magical "transformResponse" property in your $http request.
Here is an example:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: {},
    transformResponse: function (data, headersGetter, status) {
        //This was implemented since the REST service is returning a plain/text response
        //and angularJS $http module can't parse the response like that.
        return {data: data};
    }
}).success(function () {
    //Some success function
}).error(function () {
    //Some error function
});
```

For sure, you can always modify the response as you need it. :)

Cheers!

Comment: This is the solution. Should be accepted as an answer

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with invalid JSON you are returning from the server. I’ve just met with the same problem.

Looking at the source of Angular, I found a `toJSON` and `fromJSON` functions in `@module` ng that are trying to `JSON.parse()` given value if it is a string, which in your case seems to be true.

It should be easily solved by serializing data server-side, so Angular could parse it without any problem.

Good luck.

Comment: How do you return the value? Show us the server response.

Comment: ` SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1065:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8579:16)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8664:12
`